# Compute and plot 'grand' regression over multiple smaller regressions

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have grouped `Area` values, for each of which I can compute and plot regressions:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c(rep("A",8), rep("B",10), rep("C",7)),
  Area = c(1,3,2,4,3,5,7,9, rnorm(10), sample(7)),
  x = c(1:8,1:10,1:7)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = x, y = Area, group = factor(Group))) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

But what I'm looking for is **how to compute and plot what could be called a 'grand' regression for all `Area` groups**. Is this possible and how would it be possible?

**EDIT**:
My guess is that it's not enough to simply disregard the `group` variable by running a model over all `Area` and all `x` values and excluding the `group`variable. This would treat the different groups as irrelevant. In actual fact each group represents a distribution in its own right. Consider each group as collecting the values of an independent event . What I need is a model that incorporates the distinction between the groups/events while at the same time summarizing over them.

Comment: this is then similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772738/geom-smooth-custom-linear-model see, it’s difficult to visualise multidimensional models on a 2D space

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240350/custom-lm-formula-in-geom-smooth

Comment: and not the least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191606/ggplot2-geom-smooth-extended-model-for-method-lm

Comment: So are you saying that the independent variable x for Group A (x_A) should be a separate variable than the x for Group B (x_B)? And you are trying to plot 3 separate linear model, i.e. lm(Area ~ x_A); lm(Area ~ x_B); lm(Area ~ x_C)? In that case it doesn't really make sens to "summarise" over 3 separate models right? You can plot them on the same space for sure, but how are they related?

Comment: The approach for group variable in geom_smooth is more akin to a visualisation of linear mixed effect model, when the groups are random effect to the overall model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be wary of the answers using `stat_smooth`/`geom_smooth` to plot a fitted line for the disaggregated values. This simply draws a best fit line through all of the data, **ignoring how they are clustered**.

As you say in your edit, what you need is a model that can account for the fact that you have an `Area ~ X` relationship in each group:

> EDIT: My guess is that it's not enough to simply disregard the group variable by running a model over all Area and all x values and excluding the groupvariable. This would treat the different groups as irrelevant. In actual fact each group represents a distribution in its own right. Consider each group as collecting the values of an independent event . What I need is a model that incorporates the distinction between the groups/events while at the same time summarizing over them.

Without knowing more about your design, my first recommendation would be a mixed-effects model (e.g., using `lme4`).

You can fit the model, accounting for the fact that you have unique relationships in each group:

```
example_mod<- lmer(Area~
       # Fixed Effects 
       1+X+
       # Random Effects
       (1+X|Group),
     data=df, 
     REML=TRUE,
     control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=5e5)))
```

You can then extract the predicted values from this model to plot those, or calculate your own predicted values from the fixed-effects.

```
fitted(example_mod)
fixef(example_mod)
```

Comment: Thanks, Keith, really interesting and insightful. I've adapted the code to my actual data, which is pretty large. I get a warning and this output:

Comment: `Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?`

Comment: `> m_wh
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Area ~ 1 + x + (1 + x | Sequ)
   Data: wh
REML criterion at convergence: 309323.7
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr 
 Sequ     (Intercept) 625.609       
          x             4.603  -0.79
 Residual             243.591       
Number of obs: 22295, groups:  Sequ, 87
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)            x  
   978.2168      -0.7604  
optimizer (bobyqa) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings`

Comment: Is the warning to be taken serious? I'm not famiiliar with mixed effects modeling. What does the model 'say'? How is it interpreted?

Comment: Thanks Chris, that opens a pretty big can of worms, but in short I would say yes, it is important to take those warnings seriously. 

Let me link to a few things that might be helpful:
https://keithlohse.github.io/mixed_effects_models/
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X12001180?casa_token=-vsMx6K-8lUAAAAA:kCsC2lhfvevAaMr5kakrKDCKG9KaTWMvqpFTy5kpgqmp4FUOW2hZrM6kiIFuwYNsvJq4I8wF050

Comment: Then to give you a quick orientation to the model, the "fixed-effects" will refer to something like a "grand average" intercept and effect of ````x```` across you different ````Groups````.  So in a model that converges, those fixed-effects sound like what you want (conceptually) in your original question.

For the random effects, the random-intercept tells you how much the intercept varies between your different ````Groups```` and the random slope tells you how much the effect of ````x```` varies between the different ```Groups````.

Comment: Troubleshooting convergence warnings can be tricky, but the best place to start is always to make sure that there is a close correspondence between your theoretical question and your statistical model. There are also some good thread on Stack about the topic, when it comes to the nitty gritty of specific warnings/errors: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110004/how-scared-should-we-be-about-convergence-warnings-in-lme4

Comment: It seems this is quite a bit beyond me. Would you like to compute, interpret, and visualize the model based on the actual data - for a fee, obviously?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I appreciate that, but I don't have the bandwidth for it. Do you have access to a biostatistician (or similar) you could consult with? These models are relatively common in education, psychology, and ecology... so you could probably find someone in those fields who could help you out?

Answer (score 1):

use two geom_smooth and put the grouping aesthetic into each geom separately

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c(rep("A",8), rep("B",10), rep("C",7)),
  Area = c(1,3,2,4,3,5,7,9, rnorm(10), sample(7)),
  x = c(1:8,1:10,1:7)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = Area)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = factor(Group)), method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth()
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = x, y = Area)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, colour="red") +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", se = FALSE, aes(group=factor(Group)))
```

[image]

Edit: Since I'd been called out to provide more details, here is what is going on behind the scene for when you run `geom_smooth(aes(group=factor(Group))`

```
library(nlme)
fit1 <- lmList(Area ~ x|Group, data=df)
df$fit1 <- fitted(fit1)

ggplot(df, aes(x, fit1, colour=Group)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

When you add a second geom_smooth without the group factor, you are running a linear regression (method lm) for the whole data set. i.e.

```
fit2 <- lm(Area ~ x, data=df)
df$fit2 <- fitted(fit2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, fit2)) + geom_line()
```

[image]